# Swift 2 - iOS: disable a bar button

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

In the Code below, i created 2 right bar buttons using swift 2.

At this moment, i want to make something like that:

```
accountButton.disable = false
```

But that is not possible.

What is the best solution to disable this bar button ?

```
let accountImage   = UIImage(named: "account")!
let settingImage   = UIImage(named: "setting")!
let accountButton  = UIBarButtonItem(image: accountImage,  style: .Plain , target: self, action: "didTapEditButton:")

let settingButton  = UIBarButtonItem(image: settingImage,  style: .Plain, target: self, action: "didTapSearchButton:")

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [accountButton , settingButton]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [enabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarItem/enabled) property?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

**Swift 2**

```
accountButton.enabled = false
```

**Swift 3**

```
accountButton.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: it's Worked, THANK YOU @pedrouan

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIBarButtonItem`'s property `enabled` instead of `disable`